# Changes to Input Formats not saving: Default instance field is required

Tags: input-formats

When trying to make any changes to any text format, when I click "Save" Drupal returns an error message: "Default instance field is required." and the changes are not saved. Screenshot: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ff38my7f7 (Drupal version 7.30.)

Can anyone suggest what could be causing this?

Comment: Try disabling VideoJS filter (uncheck the checkbox for VideoJS filter in the settings) and try saving. Everything seems standard and should be working that's why I suggest disabling the filter settings for that contributed module.

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried that without success. Turns out it was the qTip filter causing the problem. Even when not selected the qTip filter was adding a required select field to the bottom of the form which only became visible when the qTip filter was added to the text format. Essentially an invisible required field :)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because of qTip filter (https://www.drupal.org/project/qtip) which had a required field that wasn't visible on the text format page because qTip filter wasn't selected. The required field was still part of the form (visible in source) even though it was invisible in the rendered page.